# What is the time/space complexity of my code for DisjointSets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, disjoint-sets

I have written this code for Disjoint sets

```
class DisjointSet{
    HashMap<String,String> map;

        public DisjointSet(){
            map = new HashMap<>();
        }

        /*Time complexity for this is just O(1)
         * because we are just inserting data into the HashMap
         * */
    public void makeSet(String s){
        if(map.containsKey(s))
            return;

        map.put(s, s);
    }

    /*Time complexity for this is just O(1)
     * because we are just inserting data into the HashMap
     * */
    public void Union(String p,String q){
        if(!map.containsKey(p) || !map.containsKey(q))
            return;
        map.put(p, q);

    }

    /*This is where it gets interesting*/

    public String Find(String s){
        if(s.equals(map.get(s)))
            return s;
        String parent = this.Find(map.get(s));
        map.put(s, parent);
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Note that in the Find method I have used the path-compression but I haven't used union by rank anywhere.
Will the time complexity here be equal to the the depth of the tree?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I tried solving it myself and hence the last lines. I want to make sure time complexity will be equal to the depth of the tree. It's not a homework question.

Comment: When you use path compression, but not union-by-rank, you get O(log N) *amortized* time for Find(), and O(N) worst case.